# Load jQuery UI tabs in same page using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePhp(2.5.4) with jQuery UI tabs(jquery-ui.1.8.20) to create tabs and populate contents via ajax on my view page.

My problem is when I navigate through the tabs, all new contents are placed in the same page(one below the other).

How can i make each content to appear under its own tab?

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    var st_id = <?php echo $data1['Town']['Municipality'];?>;
    //console.log(st_id);
    $(function(){
        $("#mytabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions : {
                type :"POST",
                data:{postData:st_id},
                error:function(xhr,status,index,anchor){
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Could not load tab");
                },
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my div structure

```
<div id='mytabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#content_1' title='content_1'>Tab1</a></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Tab2',array('controller' => 'Towns','action' => 'viewTown'),array('title' => 'content_2')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Accounts Records',array('controller' => 'Towns','action' => 'viewAccounts'),array('title' => 'content_3'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Population',array('controller' => 'Towns','action' => 'viewPeople'),array('title' => 'content_4')); ?></li>
    </ul>
<div id='content_2'></div>
<div id='content_3'></div>
<div id='content_4'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably some div tag is not close, be sure that all tags is appropriate closed.